# Placing borders inside a div without "box-sizing" property nor shadows

Tags: html, css, border

I'm searching a way to place a bottom-border inside a div. I searched around the web including SE) and I've found two solutions that aren't useful for me:

- Using `box-sizing: border-box;`, but it doesn't work for me. It seems that doesn't exists that property (nor Bluefish o Firefox doesn't recognize it )
- Using `box-shadow`, but the shadows surround the entire div and I only want top draw a border at the bottom of the div.

Exists a solution for this? if not, how can I solve the `box-sizing` property problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `pseudo-elements`, simply place a `pseudo-element` on the bottom with a background of your choice

Bottom only

```css
.box{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background:grey;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  position:relative;
}

.box:after{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  bottom:0;
  height:5px;
  width:100%;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Top only

```css
.box{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background:grey;
  padding-top:5px;
  position:relative;
}

.box:after{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  top:0;
  height:5px;
  width:100%;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Both top and bottom

```css
.box{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background:grey;
  padding:5px 0;
  position:relative;
}

.box:after{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  top:0;
  height:5px;
  width:100%;
  background:red;
}
  
.box:before{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  bottom:0;
  height:5px;
  width:100%;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

You can also put it on all four sides

```css
.box{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background:grey;
  padding:5px;
  position:relative;
}

.box:after{
  position:absolute;
  content:"";
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:calc(100% - 10px);
  width:calc(100% - 10px);
  border:5px solid #00CCFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Woah, that answer was very fast & useful!

Comment: You are welcome @spund3 , I have edited my answer it uses the calc property to apply borders on all four sides

Answer (score 0):

Surely `border-bottom` solves this?

```
.box{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background:grey;
  border-bottom:5px solid red;
}

<div class="box"></div>
```

I'm of a mind to say that the box-sizing declaration doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Splitting hairs. If you change the height to 95px, then you've got the same result, surely?

Comment: I was just trying to show a different way of doing it. Either way you end up with a div that is sized 200px wide and 100px high. It's less coding this way.